# thrust::device_ptr<float> has no member 'begin'

Tags: cuda, thrust

I tried to find the minimum element in an array:

```
 thrust::device_ptr<float> devPtr(d_ary);
 int minPos = thrust::min_element(devPtr.begin(), devPtr.end()) - devPtr.begin();
```

And I got the above error when compiling.

How should I fix this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific error you identify is because device pointers are not containers, and therefore have no `.begin()` or `.end()` members.
your `devPtr` is not a container, it is a device pointer usable by Thrust.
You wrapped a raw pointer to create devPtr, and the raw pointer carries with it no knowledge of the size of the data region that it is pointing to.

Pointers don't have members like begin and end.

You could fix the problem either by:

1. switching to using thrust vector containers which will have .begin and .end iterators defined for you
2. manually creating begin and end pointers for the data region (d_ary) you are accessing

Here's some example code along the lines of the latter idea above:

```
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>

#define N 256
int main()
{

  float *d_a;

  cudaMalloc((void **) &d_a, N*sizeof(float));

  thrust::device_ptr<float> dPbeg(d_a);
  thrust::device_ptr<float> dPend = dPbeg + N;
  thrust::device_ptr<float> result = thrust::min_element(dPbeg, dPend);
}
```

There is a [thrust quickstart guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) which may be of interest.  (In the interest of clarity, I have not wrapped the cudaMalloc call with any error-checking.  It's good practice to wrap cuda calls with error checking.)

Comment: now I got different error: /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/cuda/reduce.inl:224: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘thrust::detail::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’

Comment: it looks to be completely unrelated to this question.  It's probably best if you start a new question and post your code, preferably the smallest complete sample that will reproduce your error.

Comment: @user11869: Compile a `.cu` file with `nvcc`, not a `.cpp` file.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, here the `*result` will give the value of minimum element,isnt it?

Comment: How do I print the device_ptr "result" on the console? Extracting the raw_ptr from device_ptr and then printing the raw_ptr gives a segmentation fault error.

Comment: In CUDA, device pointers cannot be dereferenced in host code. This is a very basic CUDA concept. Therefore the correct approach would be to copy the data pointed to by the device pointer from device to host, and print by using (dereferencing) the host pointer.